# PHP - Show link expiration time in minutes

Tags: php

I want to set a link expiration date with php:

I want that when user creates a new short link on my website it should be automatically deleted on the fifth day of creation.

I am totally confused with the following code. I want to put this code on user's notification page, so that it can inform them how many minutes are remaing for the link to be expired.

```
<?php 
$created=time();
$expire=$created + 5;
$total_minutes=$expire / 5 / 60;
echo "Link expires in $total_minutes minutes";?>
```

It outputs an unexpected long number.

How can I implement this code so that it can output 7200 or remaining minutes?

Comment: if you only need the amount of the remained time in minutes, it is enough to print '5*24*60', where 5 stands for 5 days. The following link will give you information to accomplish your task: http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php

Comment: Where are you storing the link and the creation and expiry time of it? I assume in a database, with a key of userid?

Answer (score 2):

time() returns UNIX timestamp.

If you want human readable output, look into DateTime class in PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Example:

```
<?php

$created = new DateTime('now');
$expiration_time = new DateTime('now +5minutes');
$compare = $created->diff($expiration_time);
$expires = $compare->format('%i');

echo "Your link will expire in: " . $expires . " minutes";

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$created = strtotime('June 21st 20:00 2015'); // time when link is created
$expire = $created + 432000; // 432000 = 5 days in seconds
$seconds_until_expiration = $expire - time();
$minutes_until_expiration = round($seconds_until_expiration / 60); // convert to minutes
echo "Link expires in $minutes_until_expiration minutes";
?>
```

Note that $created shouldn't be made at script runtime, but saved somewhere, otherwise this script will always report that the link expires in 5 days.

Comment: Word is born. I haven't tested the code, and yes, I forgot to divide by 60 to coonvert to minutes. I'll edit now.

Answer (score 1):

The php function `time()` returns in seconds (since the Unix Epoch).

You adding "5" is just five seconds.

For five days you need to add sum of `5 * 24 * 60 *60` which is the number of seconds for five days.

In code:

```
$created = time();
$expires = $created + (5 * 24 * 60 * 60);

if ($expires < time()) {
    echo 'File expired';
} else {
    echo 'File expires in: ' . round(((time() + 1) - $created) / 60) . ' minutes';
}
```

Please refer to [PHP: time()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php)